# How to sum all the values that belong to the same key?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymysql

I'm pulling data from the database and assuming i have something like this:

```
    Product Name    Quantity
    a               3
    a               5
    b               2
    c               7
```

I want to sum the Quantity based on Product name, so this is what i want:

```
    product = {'a':8, 'b':2, 'c':7 }
```

Here's what I'm trying to do after fetching the data from the database:

```
    for row in result:
       product[row['product_name']] += row['quantity']
```

but this will give me: 'a'=5 only, not 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist on using loops, you can do this:

```
# fake data to make the script runnable
result = [
  {'product_name': 'a', 'quantity': 3},
  {'product_name': 'a', 'quantity': 5},
  {'product_name': 'b', 'quantity': 2},
  {'product_name': 'c', 'quantity': 7}
]

# solution with defaultdict and loops
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)
for row in result:
  d[row['product_name']] += row['quantity']

print(dict(d))
```

The output:

```
{'a': 8, 'b': 2, 'c': 7}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1: pandas**

This is one way, assuming you begin with a `pandas` dataframe `df`. This solution has O(n log n) complexity.

```
product = df.groupby('Product Name')['Quantity'].sum().to_dict()

# {'a': 8, 'b': 2, 'c': 7}
```

The idea is you can perform a `groupby` operation, which produces a series indexed by "Product Name". Then use the `to_dict()` method to convert to a dictionary.

**Option 2: collections.Counter**

If you begin with a list or iterator of results, and wish to use a `for` loop, you can use `collections.Counter` for O(n) complexity.

```
from collections import Counter

result = [['a', 3],
          ['a', 5],
          ['b', 2],
          ['c', 7]]

product = Counter()

for row in result:
    product[row[0]] += row[1]

print(product)
# Counter({'a': 8, 'c': 7, 'b': 2})
```

**Option 3: itertools.groupby**

You can also use a dictionary comprehension with `itertools.groupby`. This requires sorting beforehand.

```
from itertools import groupby

res = {i: sum(list(zip(*j))[1]) for i, j in groupby(sorted(result), key=lambda x: x[0])}

# {'a': 8, 'b': 2, 'c': 7}
```

Comment: What happens with the `groupby` if the products are sorted by some key other than `'product_name'`?

Comment: `pandas.DataFrame.groupby` does not require explicit sorting beforehand. This happens in the background. That's why it's an O(n log n) solution versus collections.Counter O(n) solution.

Comment: Thanks for the information, learned something new! I found the behavior of `groupby` on lists was somewhat surprising.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin, Yes  - shouldn't confuse pandas `groupby` on dataframe with itertools `groupby` on list. The `itertools` method requires explicit sorting first.

Answer (score 0):

Use `tuple` to store the result.

**Edit:**

---

Not clear if the data mentioned is really a dataframe.

If yes then `li = [tuple(x) for x in df.to_records(index=False)]`

---

```
li = [('a', 3), ('a', 5), ('b', 2), ('c', 7)]
d = dict()
for key, val in li:
    val_old = 0
    if key in d:
        val_old = d[key]
    d[key] = val + val_old
print(d)
```

### Output

```
{'a': 8, 'b': 2, 'c': 7}
```

Comment: I don't think that the OP can easily influence the format of the data returned from the query. What is the `int(str(...))` good for? I think the dunder `__contains__` should not be called explicitly, use `x in d` instead. Furthermore, take a look at the other answers: one is with `defaultdict`, the other is with `Counter`. Both versions seem slightly more concise.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention pandas

```
df.set_index('ProductName').Quantity.sum(level=0).to_dict()
Out[20]: {'a': 8, 'b': 2, 'c': 7}
```